# How do I get a menu grandchild to show on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I believe this issue is with the JavaScript/Jquery 3.3.1, not assessing the grandchild of the menu, but I am lost on how to get this accomplished. Any help would be appreciated.

The HTML is a menu block create in Drupal 7. The leaf class is not used in my CSS.

```
<div id="block-menu-menu-demo" class="block block-menu contextual-links-region">
<h2>Family &amp; Community Menu</h2>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf"><a href="/fce">Main Page</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/families">For Families</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/schools">For Schools</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/communities">For Communities</a></li>
    <li class="last expanded"><a href="/sde/parent-community-engagement">Related Topics</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="/sde/21cclc">21st CCLC</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/summer-learning">Summer Learning</a></li>
            <li class="last expanded"><a href="/sde/chronic-absenteeism">Chronic Absenteeism</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first last leaf"><a href="/absenteeism-tool-kit">Toolkit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS could be cleaned up, but it works.

```
    /*SIDE NAV*/

#block-menu-menu-demo {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'RobotoLight', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: .8em;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 77;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo a {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo ul {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li {
    background-color: #4176c3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li:hover {
    background-color: #96b9ed;
    color: #235196 !important;
}
/*Adding this creates a hover on li since a is inside the li and we can't change that.*/

#block-menu-menu-demo li:hover>a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #235196 !important;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li a:hover {
    color: #235196 !important;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li a:active {
    color: #000 !important;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo h2 {
    background-color: #2b3c4f;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 12px;
}
/*Expanded subnav action*/

#block-menu-menu-demo h2, #block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded {
    position: relative;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo h2:after, #block-menu-menu-demo .expanded:after {
    border: solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 7px;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo h2:after {
    border-top-color: #2b3c4f;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo .menu {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo .expanded {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo .expanded ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded:after {
    border-top-color: #69afff;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo .expanded ul.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 250px;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li.expanded {
    background-image: url('http://www.ok.gov/sde/sites/ok.gov.sde/files/side_menu_droparrow-clear.png');
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/* Or size of icon + spacing */
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li:last-child, #block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded {
    border-bottom: none;
}
/*Expanded subnav*/

#block-menu-menu-demo li li {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-left: 5px;/*width: 250px;*/
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li li a {
    color: #555 !important;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li li a:active {
    color: #000 !important;
}
#block-menu-menu-demo li li:hover {
    background-color: #CCC !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
    // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block-menu-menu-demo > ul > li > a').click

        (function () {
        $('#block-menu-menu-demo li').removeClass('first');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('first');
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('first');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#block-menu-menu-demo ul ul:visible').slideUp

                ('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }
        if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party sites so that we can run it. You can just insert your code into a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in your selectors. You are being too specific. The selector for your click `#block-menu-menu-demo > ul > li > a` only works for an anchor at the first level of your menu structure. The deeper nested anchors never even trigger this.

You also had some weirdness when attempting to "close" an open menu. Again this selector `#block-menu-menu-demo ul ul:visible` is too specific. I reworked that part to use `siblings()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#block-menu-menu-demo a').click

            (function () {
            $('#block-menu-menu-demo li').removeClass('first');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('first');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();

            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('first');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).siblings('ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length === 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
/*SIDE NAV*/

    #block-menu-menu-demo {
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'RobotoLight', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: .8em;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 77;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo a {
        border-bottom: none !important;
        color: #FFF !important;
        display: block !important;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo ul {
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li {
        background-color: #4176c3;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        list-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-top: 12px;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li:hover {
        background-color: #96b9ed;
        color: #235196 !important;
    }
    /*Adding this creates a hover on li since a is inside the li and we can't change that.*/

    #block-menu-menu-demo li:hover>a {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: #235196 !important;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li a:hover {
        color: #235196 !important;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li a:active {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo h2 {
        background-color: #2b3c4f;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 0 8px 12px;
    }
    /*Expanded subnav action*/

    #block-menu-menu-demo h2, #block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded {
        position: relative;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo h2:after, #block-menu-menu-demo .expanded:after {
        border: solid transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-width: 7px;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        top: 100%;
        width: 0;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo h2:after {
        border-top-color: #2b3c4f;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo .menu {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo .expanded {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo .expanded ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 12px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded:after {
        border-top-color: #69afff;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo .expanded ul.menu {
        display: none;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li.expanded {
        background-image: url('files/side_menu_droparrow-clear.png');
        background-position: right center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;/* Or size of icon + spacing */
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li:last-child, #block-menu-menu-demo ul.expanded {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    /*Expanded subnav*/

    #block-menu-menu-demo li li {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding-left: 5px;/*width: 250px;*/
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li li a {
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li li a:active {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
    #block-menu-menu-demo li li:hover {
        background-color: #CCC !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-menu-menu-demo" class="block block-menu contextual-links-region">
    <h2>Family &amp; Community Menu</h2>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf"><a href="/fce">Main Page</a></li>
        <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/families">For Families</a></li>
        <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/schools">For Schools</a></li>
        <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/communities">For Communities</a></li>
        <li class="last expanded"><a href="/sde/parent-community-engagement">Related Topics</a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="/sde/21cclc">21st CCLC</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="/sde/summer-learning">Summer Learning</a></li>
                <li class="last expanded"><a href="/sde/chronic-absenteeism">Chronic Absenteeism</a>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="first last leaf"><a href="/absenteeism-tool-kit">Toolkit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```